# When I will click on a href link it will check all checkbox after related this link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a links named `All` and `none`. When I click on `All`, I want it to check all checkboxes related with it and change it's link text to `none`.

When I click again I want it to uncheck all of the checkboxes.

I have some code which I can use to check all boxes with a checkbox. But now I want to check all boxes with a link. Please see, here is this demo code ([also on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kdEmH/24/)):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

    // add multiple select / deselect functionality
    $("#selectall").click(function () {
          $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });

    // if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
    // and viceversa
    $(".case").click(function(){

        if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
            $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
        }

    });
});
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[type=checkbox]").click(updateCount);

        updateCount();

        function updateCount () {
          var count = $("input[type=checkbox].case:checked").length;

          $("#count").text(count);
          $("#status").toggle(count > 0);
        };
      });
    </script>enter code here
  </head>
  <body>
    <H2>why counting wrong in crome, Ie </H2>

select all
    <input type="checkbox" id="selectall"/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="1"/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="2"/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="3"/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="4"/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="5"/>
    <div id="status">
      <p id="count">0</p>
    </div>
  </body>




http://jsfiddle.net/kdEmH/24/
```

Comment: I checked your code in chrome and safari, and it seems to work fine. It shows 5 when select all is checked, and hides the count when select all is unchecked.

Comment: please see example on http://jsfiddle.net/kdEmH/24/

Comment: Yeah i commented after viewing your fiddle. What do you exactly want to achieve?

Comment: I have a href link now I want to check all checkbox by clicking on this link. When i will click in it It will check all checkbox and when i will click again it will uncheck all check box. just it.
http://jsfiddle.net/kdEmH/24/

Comment: please see http://jsfiddle.net/Taslimkhan/kdEmH/28/ I have updated.

Comment: If it solved your problem, set post as answered

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML part, add a link like :

```
<a href="#" id="select_all_link" title="Select all">Click me to toggle all checkboxes</a>
```

In your Javascript part, add :

```
 $("a#select_all_link").click(function(){
   if($('.case:checked').length > 0)
      $('.case').attr('checked', false);
   else
      $('.case').attr('checked', true);
 });
```

Please see working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/kdEmH/32/)

**Edit :** Names now changed wrt checkboxes state (checked or not)

Comment: thank you very much boss your answer is correct but the text is not chainging with clicking.

Comment: I've edited my link (new one also [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AnthonyLeGovic/kdEmH/32/)). It update the text of the new link and the "global" checkbox when all/none of checkboxes are (un)checked

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kdEmH/27/) :

Add a `<A>` tag to html code:

```
<a id="selectall" href="#">select all</a>
```

Add this function to java-script code:

```
$(function(){
  var state=true;
$("#selectall").click(function () {
      $('.case').attr('checked', state);
    state=!state;
    var obj = document.getElementById("selectall");
    if(state)
    {
         obj.innerText="select all";
    }
    else
    {
         obj.innerText="clear all";
    }
});
```

**Complete Code**

```
    $(function(){
      var state=true;
    // add multiple select / deselect functionality
    $("#selectall").click(function () {
          $('.case').attr('checked', state);
  state=!state;
        var obj = document.getElementById("selectall");
        if(state)
        {
             obj.innerText="select all";
        }
        else
        {
             obj.innerText="clear all";
        }
    });


    // if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
    // and viceversa
    $(".case").click(function(){

        if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
            $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
        }

    });
});
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[type=checkbox]").click(updateCount);

        updateCount();

        function updateCount () {
          var count = $("input[type=checkbox].case:checked").length;

          $("#count").text(count);
          $("#status").toggle(count > 0);
        };
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to get it this way, i just guessed a link `<a>` with an id of `#allNone` and put the `.prop()` function to check and uncheck the checkboxes:

```
$('#allNone').on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
(this.text == 'Check All') ? 
    $(this).text('Check None').nextAll('.case').prop('checked', true) :
    $(this).text('Check All').nextAll('.case').prop('checked', false);
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kdEmH/31/)

Answer (score 1):

Might not be what you're looking for, but it's a quick way of doing the toggle thing:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var $cbs = $('.case');
    $cbs.prop('checked', !$cbs.prop('checked'));
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href='' id="link" data-action="all">All</a>
    <input type="checkbox" class="case" value="1"/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="case" value="2"/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="case" value="3"/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="case" value="4"/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="case" value="5"/>
    <div id="status">
        <p id="count">0</p>
    </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("#link").click(function(){
        $a = $(this);
        var action = $a.data('action');
        if(action == "all"){
            $('.case').attr("checked","true");
            $a.text("None").data("action","none");
        }
        if(action == "none"){
            $('.case').removeAttr("checked");
            $a.text("All").data("action","all");
        }
        updatecount();
        return false;
    })
    $(".case").click(function(){
       if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length){
            $("#link").text("None").data("action","none");
       }else{
            $("#link").text("All").data("action","all");
       }
       updatecount();
    })
})
var updatecount = function(){
    $("#count").text($(".case:checked").length);
}
</script>
</html>
```